# pyspark not able to integrate properly with python udf with ebcdic value

Tags: python, pyspark

I have written code to convert a utf-8 to comp-3 and encode ebcdic(cp037) before sending it to mainframe. Below is the code piece:

```
from os import sep


def pad_string(output_str, output_length):
    output_str = '0' * (output_length * 2 - len(output_str)) + output_str
    # Return padded string
    return output_str


# Convert Hex to EBCDIC
def to_ebcdic(input_str, input_length, bytecount):
    # Store the last character
    sign_char = input_str[-1]
    # Concatenate the remaining character and the sign character
    if sign_char == "D":
        # Remove the first character
        stripped_str = input_str[1:]
        input_hex = stripped_str[:input_length - 1] + sign_char
    elif sign_char == "F":
        input_hex = input_str[:input_length] + sign_char
    else:
        # Remove the first character
        stripped_str = input_str[1:]
        input_hex = stripped_str[:input_length] + sign_char
    # Padding if input_str is less than bytecount
    pad_str = pad_string(input_hex, bytecount)
    # Convert the hex string to bytes
    input_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(pad_str)
    # Decode the bytes using EBCDIC encoding
    ebcdic_str = input_bytes.decode('cp037')
    # Return the decoded string
    return ebcdic_str


def signed_comp3(decimal_num, bytecount):
    # Determine the sign of the number
    if decimal_num >= 0:
        sign_nibble = "1100"  # C for positive numbers
    else:
        sign_nibble = "1101"  # D for negative numbers
        decimal_num = abs(decimal_num)
    # Convert the decimal number to a string of BCD digits
    bcd_str = ''.join([f"{int(d):04b}" for d in str(decimal_num)])
    bcd_len = len(bcd_str)
    # Add a leading nibble of "1111" to indicate that the number is packed in COMP-3 format
    bcd_str = "1111" + bcd_str + sign_nibble
    # Pad with a trailing nibble of "0000" if the number of BCD digits is odd
    if bcd_len % 2 == 1:
        bcd_str += "0000"
    # Group the BCD digits into pairs of bytes
    byte_pairs = [bcd_str[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(bcd_str), 8)]
    # Convert each byte pair to its hexadecimal equivalent
    hex_str = ''.join([f"{int(pair, 2):02X}" for pair in byte_pairs])
    # To EBCDIC
    output_str = to_ebcdic(hex_str, len(str(decimal_num)), bytecount)
    print(f'signed_comp3 ebcdic byte count for {decimal_num}: {len(output_str)}')
    # Return EBCDIC characters
    return output_str
```

When I import this function as `udf` in `pyspark`, the `ebcdic` value is showing junk value. `pyspark` code is below:

i have written code to convert a utf-8 to comp-3 and encode ebcdic(cp037) before sending it to mainframe. Below is the code piece:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print("spark session, logger and configuration information initialization starts")
        spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .enableHiveSupport() \
            .appName("dl_extraction") \
            .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
            .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
            .getOrCreate()
    log4j = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
    logger = log4j.LogManager.getLogger("custom_logger")
    log_level = log4j.Level.INFO
    logger.setLevel(log_level)
    print("logger initialized ")
    logger.info("logger initialized")
    df = spark.sql('select * from cstonedbintegration.triumph_one_gar_billed_unbilled_poc')
    df.printSchema()
    df.select('cstone_feed_key', 'dcontrolsequencenumber_test').show()
    signed_length = 7
    unsigned_length = 5
    print('lengths', signed_length, unsigned_length)
    df1 = df.withColumn("newcol1",
                            signed_comp3_udf('cstone_feed_key', lit(signed_length))).withColumn(
            "newcol2", unsigned_comp3_udf('dcontrolsequencenumber_test', lit(unsigned_length))) \
            .select('cstone_feed_key', 'newcol1', 'dcontrolsequencenumber_test', 'newcol2')
    print('before concatenation')
    df1.printSchema()
    df1.show(truncate=False)
    df2=df1.withColumn('newcol11',df1['newcol1']).withColumn('newcol21',df1['newcol2']).select('cstone_feed_key','newcol11','dcontrolsequencenumber_test','newcol21')
    print('after doing decoding')
    df2.printSchema()
    df2.show(truncate=False)
    print('comparison result')
    b_col_length = [15, 7, 10, 5]
    df2 = df2.withColumn('onecol', concat(*(df2.columns))).select('onecol')
    print('after concatenation')
    df2.printSchema()
    df2.show(truncate=False)
    df2.coalesce(1).write.format('text').mode('overwrite').save(
            '/axp/aet/gardpa/dev/datalake/test/comp3debug2_outputdata/')
        print('processing_end')
```